# Power booster 12V to 36V for LED

Tags: power, led-driver

I am busy with making a power booster from 12V to 36V to feed a LED with, the PWM is not the problem, but the coil, and the parallel schottky diode and to make a max level circuit is more difficult. The parallel Schottky get very fast warm, while I use a SD560 60V/5A, but when i put my design in ITspice then the simulator shows that there is going 90Amp through the diode. So i guess the coil is not good. I have a EE core with 6 windings and need to make from 12V max 36V to connect a 100W LED on but that I can dim to. The mosfet does not get warm anymore since I have raised the frequency from 30Khz to 187kHz. To limit the voltage, I have used a BC547 with a 100 ohm resistor to gnd, and a 10k preset to the output voltage, but for some reason there goes a enormous high amp through the preset and get hot very soon, while in the simulator there just goes 8mA through it. I can't put my PWM higher then 25%, then it goes above the 40V. I am fighting with this circuit now for 6 months, and I don't get it right. [image]

Hereby the final and tested circuit. The PWM i made here keeps the freq. on the same level, but it just changes the duty cycle from 15% to 45%. If you just use a car battery for your design then you need to higher the value of R3 a bit to 13k ohm. 
[image: Final tested circuit.]

Comment: I read just words and see no circuit. Nobody here is a mind reader so post the circuit if you want help and make sure you give proper details on the coil.

Comment: Really!? You dump this verbal diarrhea on us with runon sentences, no paragraph breaks, and NOT EVEN A SCHEMATIC!? (duh!) -1 for the annoying and sloppy writing, and closing because without a schematic we can't tell what is asked.  Next time show some respect to the volunteer you seek a favor from.

Comment: I am sorry, i didn't want to upset anybody with my question. It is the first time i post here. I have changed R3 and R2 for a preset. The coil is a EE core with the demensions L55 mm x T26 mm x H45 mm. I have used 3 wires from 0.8mm and made 6 turns with it.

Comment: Your title is wrong. You are boosting _voltage_, not _power_. The power in will be the same as power out + some losses. You will boost from low voltage and high current to a higher voltage and lower current.

Comment: Yes, that is what i wrote first in the head line, but the site given me a error so i had to change it to be able to post it.

Comment: What is D4 doing? It clamps the voltage at the junction of M1 and L1 at no more than one diode drop above V1. There is no way the circuit can work. Is there a reason not to use a controller IC?

Comment: D4 is to avoid that the voltage spikes. I know it doesn't works, there is every time something that gets to hot or burns out. There for i was asking people there help here to get it right. Well, in my country we just have some basic components, and ordering from abroad is a very expensive hobby so to say, that i can't effort. I am just a beginner in electronics and read and try what i find on the internet. But this one i need for my work.

Comment: I have not analyze the circuit, but definintely, remove D4. It is a boost circuit, you want the "flyback" voltage. The spike would already be limited by the output capacitor C3. By having D4, L1 cannot discharge effectively, the current probably rises every cycle until something breaks. Secondarily, the NE555 may be too weak to switch M1 quickly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Rioraxe, ok i have removed D4. The NE555 does 187kHz what i measure, the M1 should be able to do 58Mhz what i calculated. I think to that the current rises very high, but i don't know how to limit that. I try to limit the output voltage with the BC547 and the resistor with a preset, but that does not work well. If i have limited it to 36V and i put the pot up, then it goes over the 40V again, i dont' get why.

Comment: @Claudia unless you live in North Korea I have a hard time buying the "in my country" excuse, even though it is a very common expression to use here. Why don't you write out your country, and maybe someone will be able to help you? There's nothing wrong trying to build a switch regulator with a 555, but if you really want a working circuit maybe there is a better option.

Comment: @ pipe, i live in Romania. We have just one electronic component store a few villages away from here, and that one has a limited assortment. I want to build this project because i need more light for video recordings for educational use at schools. I do interviews with people about their profession so children can make better choices what they want to study later. Those 100Watt LED's were not very expensive, so that is why i want to make this working.

Comment: @Claudia Are places like http://ro.rsdelivers.com/ or http://ro.farnell.com/ out of the question? Maybe they do not sell to individuals, or charge too much for shipping, but it's worth checking out.

Comment: @pipe Thank you so much, i will call them tomorrow if they deliver in my village to. Here it is always the question if some one want to send to your village. It mostly depends on the priest from the village. That is how it goes in Romania :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am too lazy to figure out how your NE555 control circuit works, but here are some basic parameters:

The inductor charges and discharges per cycle and the ratio of the time is (Vout-Vin):Vin, which is 2:1. Adding some extra inactive time to ensure discontinuous mode, so the ratio of (charge time, discharge time, inactive time) can be set to (2/4, 1/4, 1/4) of a cycle.

With the maximum output current being 3A, the peak inductor current \$I_{peak} = 3A \times 4 \times 2 = 24A\$. The multiplicative factor of 4 comes from the discharge time being 1/4 of a cycle. The factor of 2 comes from the discharge being a triangular ramp.

**That means the power elements M1, L1, D1 (and C3) must be spec'ed to 24A plus margin.**

The switch-on-time at maximum load would be:
\$ t_{on\_max} = \frac{2}{4} \times \frac{1}{freq}=5us \$ for \$freq = 100KHz\$ for example.

The inductance required $$ L_1 = t_{on\_max} \times \frac{(V_{in}=12V)}{(I_{peak}=24A)}$$
Staying with \$freq=100KHz\$
Then \$L_1 = 2.5uH\$ (and from above, saturation current >24A)

There are various schemes to provide regulation. A common scheme is to use constant frequency and varies \$t_{on}\$ to achieve regulation, that would be classic PWM. This need is the reason for the suggestion of using a switching regulator IC (which could be quite cheap and common in the US) and one way how the 555 circuit needs to function.

---

Response to comment:

The output of a LED is controlled by its current. For a LED spec'ed for 36V/3.4A, the interpretation would be that the maximum output is at 3.4A and the corresponding forward voltage (Vf) across it would be around 36V. The Vf will vary.

If your 555 control circuit is working properly, then you would want to change it to regulate based on output current, which is not difficult to do. The feedback voltage threshold is the Vbe of Q1 (around 0.6V for a guess). So keep R5 as the current sense resistor and connect Q1-base to it (while disconnected from the existing voltage feedback resistors). For regulation of 3A, the resistor should be around 0.6V/3A = 0.2ohm. By the way, it is not a bad way to get the 0.2ohm by paralleling five 1-ohm resistors for prototyping. That way, you can adjust current by increasing or decreasing the number of 1-ohm resistors in parallel.

---

I have tried to understand the 555 circuit a little more. It has a problem of not controlling the maximum input current especially during start-up. I don't see any very simple way to address that fully. So I would start with a duty cycle of no more than 1/3 instead of 1/2 and hope that the components and upstream power supply can work through the start-up.

Using ton_max of 1/3 cycle, then t_discharge is 1/6 cycle. Then \$I_{peak} = 3A \times 6 \times 2 = 36A\$.

Using the 0.011mH inductor you have, \$t_{on\_max} = L_1 \times I_{peak} / V_{in} = 33us\$. So the cycle time is 3 x 33us = 100us, that gives a switching frequency 10KHz. (You can change the inductance to get a different switching frequency and t_on timing.)

Change the feedback to regulate on current. Use R5 as the current sense resistor. The value should be around R5 = (Vbe=0.6V)/3A = 0.2ohm. It is not a bad idea to parallel five 1ohm resistor to get the 0.2ohm. That way you can increase or decrease the regulated current by changing the number of the 1ohm resistors in parallel. You can start with higher resistance (= lower output current) at the beginning of your test. The total power dissipation of the resistor would be around 0.6V^2 / 0.2 = 1.8W. So that is not a trivial waste of power and these resistors are going to get hot.

Add another transistor in parallel to Q1 and connect the base of it to the junction of R5 and LED through a resistor (100 or 220 ohms is fine).

Set R2, R3, R7 to limit the output voltage to probably around 40V.

For strictly LED load, the voltage or current ripples do not have to be in 1% range. Change C3 to as low as 100uF. That helps with the start-up problem. This cap need to withstand very high ripple current of 36A. One way is to parallel a number of ceramic capacitors.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, now i understand why my schottky diode gets hot, it just does till 5A. I will look how to solve that. M1 can handle that kind of amps but the coil i must change then to. The PWM i can bring easy back to 100kHz.

Comment: Well, i removed the R5, and placed the preset between the pot and the c1 before it goes to the 555. I got now 35.4V and i measure that the LED uses 1.34Amp, don't know how that is possible because it is a 100W LED at 36V/3.4A says the spec. The M1 should do 200V/50Amp....yet the M1 get warm. Between the 12V battery and the circuit i measure 5.38Amp. The diode D3 does not get warm. I am on 104Khz now. So, if the Ipeak get 30A then why does the M1 gets warm? I do use a radiator from 5x4x3 cm. The coil gets warm to.

Comment: The maximum voltage and current ratings of a component gives the upper limits that the component can operate reliably. They do not imply anything about the power dissipation. The MOSFET and the inductor L1 (to a lesser extent, D3) are expected to dissipate power to get hot. And the MOSFET most likely does require a heat sink.

Comment: yes i have a heat sink on the mosfet from 5x4x3 cm. I just don't understand why it does not work for me, because on some websites i see people using very small coils and they can use a higher current. How can i avoid that dissipate power?

Comment: Depending on the optimization, the power dissipation of the MOSFET can vary. For example, it is important to have enough gate drive to switch off the MOSFET quickly. But for a 100W boost circuit, it seems unlikely that it can be without heat sink. By increasing the frequency, the size of the inductor can go down drastically. The switching control and gate drive becomes more critical with increased frequency and the power dissipation is likely to increase.

Comment: Ok, so if i understand it right, the gate/source is now 12v so i should lower this to 5 volts for a faster switch off? The frequency i can increase easily. I will try it tomorrow, thank you so much i will let you know the results.

Comment: The MOSFET IRFP260N will not turn on enough for this application with 5V Vgs.

One way to get faster turn off is to have a gate driver that can sink larger current, probably in the 0.5-1A range for the IRFP260N. Also bigger is not necessarily better for the MOSFET. For example, the IRFP260N is rated for 200V (while 60V is adequate), that leads to a bigger transistor with larger gate capacitance. A 60V MOSFET will tend to have significantly smaller gate capacitance and faster switching characteristic.

Comment: I have tried with a BUZ11 on a big radiator, PWM on 160kHz, but that one blew up in the very first nano second....it truly exploded in two peaces. Now i placed the IRFP260N on a CPU heat sink and it gets less fast warm, also the coil gets less fast warm then. And i placed a resistor from 10k between ground and gate to get a lower voltage on the gate.

Comment: The gate voltage is now 11V.

Comment: When I put this circuit in the Ltspice simulator, then it shows on the M1 drain 30Amp.

Comment: It is a tough way to start learning switching PS using a 555 for a moderate-pwer (100W) design. You must not let the duty cycle exceeds around 1/4 as discussed above. Otherwise, the 555 circuit cannot handle continuous current operation and things can blow up in an instance. Maybe that was what happened to the BUZ11, otherwise the BUZ11 should work. Like most designs, it involves a series of tradeoffs. With the 555, stay with 100KHz or lower until you understand the tradeoffs and are able to extract favorable outcomes. (Gate voltage of 11V is fine for IRFP260N).

Comment: It is indeed not easy to work with this design. On it self it works, but it is wasting a lot of energy that turns into heat. I do see it is a matter of balance to find between the switching frequence and the inductors capability to store energy avoiding saturation. There are many websites about this subject to find, but all are using different calculations and different advises regarding the coil. Some say 2uH some say 5uH, some say 20AWG for wire some say 15 AWG. But what IC, or circuit would be easier to work with to make a switching PS?

Comment: I have great news :-) I got 27.4V with 106kHz and a duty cycle from 23.1% with a coil from 3 x 0,8mm wires 2 turns, and the mosfet does not get warm anymore, and the coil get just a bit warm, but not hot. So i am just missing 9V to get the 36V. But it is a hugh improvement as what it was in the past. How do i get the last 9V now?

Comment: The coil i measured and it is 0.011 milli Henry.

Comment: I make a mistake in the previous comment, the duty cycle should be no more than 1/2 (not 1/4). So let the duty cycle go up, that would deliver more power to the output. I just noticed that you gave the dimensions of the core, it is much too big. You need to find a more suitable core. As outlined above, for 100KHz, \$t_{on}\$ max around 5us, inductance should be around 2.5uH. With the existing components, you can experiment with lower frequency like 50KHz, \$t_{on}\$ max around 10us, get the inductance close to 5uH.

Comment: http://www.ebay.com/itm/100W-DC-DC-Boost-Converter-10V-32V-to-12V-60V-Step-Up-Power-Supply-Module-New-/361282719853?hash=item541e20d06d:g:OtgAAOSwBahVOvc8 just as an example, with pictures of a completed module. The ebay stuffs often have exaggerated specs. I don't know how that would work in practice. Also, for driving a LED, you want regulated current, not voltage.

Comment: Yes i have had 3 of such modules, they all blew up, they don't go higher then 33V and then the LED's give 75% light. I have tried with the core from that print, but people from a other forum said that the core was saturating, so i used a bigger one. Just in that other forum the people where less skilled then you are. The current i measure when i put it on 36V is 1.48Amp, while the specs of the LED say's it is 3.4Amp.  But i don't know how to regulate the Amp's. I just see when i put the voltage on 21V then the LED is less bright then when i put it on 36V.

Comment: I would like to make a astable pwm with a duty cycle from 10-50% but the circuit's i found are or fixed duty cycle or when you can regulate it then it is from 2 till 98%. I will try today those smaller coils on 100kHz, i didn't try that yet.

Comment: I have now done with the coil from that print i got 35.3V  at 84.5kHz with a duty cycle from 35.6% and the core gets slowly hot after 5 minutes. At 33V the core does not get warm at all. So that will be at a duty cycle from 30% i think. So what is the trick?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i can understand this better now. I will try this tomorrow. Have a great old and new year tonight!

Comment: @rioraxes Happy new year! The problem is solved, it finally functions very good. Thank you so much for your help, you are a very good teacher! It is not just solved but i understand now how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The control loop improbably unstable -- too much gain & no compensation.

In a boost converter, you have to limit the maximum duty cycle, or you'll get foldback, and uncontrolled currents.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But what must i change to get it right?

Comment: Buy an IC built for this purpose. A 555 is not a good base to build a boost converter with.

Comment: Well that is in my country a bit difficult, here they just sell some basic components. So in that matter i am a bit limited unfortunately.